# how to check if there is content in multiple indexes of a list in one statement (python)

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am creating an inventory equipping system for a text-based RPG I am making. The actual inventory is a list with 5 indexes. Every item in my game can only go into specific slots of the inventory, for example, a sword can go into the first slot (Melee weapons only) and into either of two Miscellaneous slots.

If the player decides to pick up an item in the game and it happens to be a sword, here is the code:

```
Inventory = [None] * 5
def PickUpItem(self):
    if self.Slot == 1:
        if not Inventory[0]:
            Inventory[0] = self.Name
```

So I have checked if the sword slot is empty and available, but if it isn't, I would like to check if either indexes 3 or 4 are empty and available. Then, if possible I would like to set put the sword into the available index (put the item into the empty Misc slot).

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions to build a list of available indices and then select the first into which the item can go. Here's an example:

**inventory_test.py**

```
inventory = [ 'full', None, 'full', None, None ]
melee_indices = ( 0, 3, 4 )

def add_item(name):
    indices = [ i for i in melee_indices if inventory[i] is None]

    if len(indices) > 0:
        inventory[indices[0]] = name
        return True

    return False

print repr(inventory)

add_item('sword')

print repr(inventory)
```

Result:

```
['full', None, 'full', None, None]
['full', None, 'full', 'sword', None]
```

Comment: Could you please explain how your code works, mainly the new `indices` list, I don't really understand its purpose. Also explain the if statement, please.

Comment: The indices list holds the indices that are `None` in the inventory list. The if statement ensures that there are actually any indices so that `indices[0]` doesn't throw an out of bounds error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if jparonson's code is more or less efficient than the following code I wrote:

```
Inventory = [None] * 5

def PickUpItem(self):
    if self.Slot == 1:
        if not Inventory[0]:
            Inventory[0] = self.Name
        elif not Inventory[3]:
            Inventory[3] = self.Name
        elif not Inventory[4]:
            Inventory[4] = self.Name
        else:
            print(PlayerName, 'cannot carry any more with him!')
```

keeping in mind that later in the game there could be five total Miscellaneous slots/ indices.

But for now, I think I'll wait until that time and do further testing. Thank you!